# Need value of span ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a website where a span ID changes value when you add value in another box.

I'm trying to fill the box and get the changed value of span ID using JavaScript. 
I do not get the value, instead I get back `""`

using jquery 
    `("#spanid").text();`

Some code is like this where `abc` is the value I change and I want the value of spans with `id` of `spanid`.

```
var abcdef=[] 
$("#abc").val(123);
abcdef.push($("#spanid").text())
```

Comment: Please include your code here ... just the relevant part to recreate the problem, in this scenario will be just the html of your sapn and input and the JS to trigger the event

Comment: added the necessary code, cant add the whole thing, its too big

Comment: Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).